# Firebird DB - monitoring table

Tags: linux, database, monitoring, firebird

I have recently just started working with firebird DB v2.1 on a Linux Redhawk 5.4.11 system. I am trying to create a monitor script that gets kicked off via a cron job. However I am running into a few issues and I was hoping for some advice...

First off I have read through most of the documentation that come with the firebird DB and a lot of the documentation that is provided on their site. I have tried using the gstat tool which is supplied but that didn't seem to give me the kind of information I was looking for. I ran across README.monitoring_tables file which seemed to be exactly what I wanted to monitor. Yet this is where I started to hit a snag in my progress....

After running from logging into the db via isql, I run `SELECT MON$PAGE_READS, MON$PAGE_WRITES FROM MON$IO_STATS;` I was able to get some numbers which seemed okay. However upon running the command again it appeared the data was stale because the numbers were not updating. I waited 1 minute, 5 minutes, 15 minutes and all the data was the same during each. Once I logged off and back on to run the command again the data changed. It appears that only on a relog does the data refresh and yet I am not sure if even then the data is correct.

My question is now am I even doing this correct? Are these commands truly monitoring my db or are just monitoring the command itself? Also why does it take a relog to refresh the statistics? One thing I was worried about was inconsistency in my data. In other words my system was running yet when I would logon each time the read/writes were not linearly increasing. They would vary from 10k to 500 to 2k. Any advice or help would be appreciated!

Comment: I have retagged to Firebird because your question is also relevent for newer versions than Firebird 2.1. I have removed the isql tag, as that refers to a Sybase product (and the fact you use the Firebird isql tool is not really relevant for the question).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you query a monitoring table, a snapshot of the monitoring information is created so the contents of the monitoring tables are stable for the rest of the transaction. You need to commit and start a new transaction if you want fresh information. Firebird always uses a transaction (and isql implicitly starts a transaction if none was started explicitly).

This is also documented in `doc/README.monitoring_tables` (at least in the Firebird 2.5 version):

> A snapshot is created the first time any of the monitoring tables is being selected from in the given transaction and it's preserved until the transaction ends, so multiple queries (e.g. master-detail ones) will always return the consistent view of the data. In other words, the monitoring tables always behave like a snapshot (aka consistency) transaction, even if the host transaction has been started with another isolation level. **To refresh the snapshot, the current transaction should be finished and the monitoring tables should be queried in the new transaction context.**

(emphasis mine)

Note that depending on your monitoring needs, you should also look at the [trace functionality](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/2_5/rnfb25-trace.html) that was introduced in Firebird 2.5.

Comment: Wow I completely missed that in the document. So since I am new to DBs I am going to assume that get a new transaction you need to quit and relaunch the isql tool? In other words. Lets say I had my monitoring script launch by a cron job to monitor stats I would have to keep relogging into the db instead of just waking up my session to collect the statistics again, right?

Comment: In isql you can type "commit;" , then try your query again.

Comment: You simply call `COMMIT;`